# How to integrate Kubernetes Nginx Ingress with Consul and Consul Connect

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, consul, nginx-ingress

I have a k8s cluster with an nginx based ingress and multiple services (ClusterIP). I want to use Consul as a service mesh and documentation is very clear on how to set up and govern communication between services. What is not clear though is how to setup the nginx ingress to talk to these services via the injected sidecar connect proxies using mutual ssl. I'm using cert-manager to automatically provision and terminate ssl at the ingress. I need to secure the communication between the ingress and the services with Consul provisioned mutual SSL. Any documentation related to this scenario will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

You would inject the sidecar into the ingress-nginx controller and have it talk to backend services just like any other service-to-service thing. This will probably require overriding a lot of the auto-generated config so I'm not sure it will be as useful as you hope.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to confirm. In theory it should work. But there is zero documentation on how to do it. I'm starting to believe that this is not supported officially. Hashicorp has nice documentation on how to integrate with Ambassador though. No dice for nginx